# Jquery tool tip on right of div or anchor tag

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Not Able to get the desired results for jquery tooltip. i want it to show on right side of my anchor tag but its not happening.
Go through this [Jquery UI tool tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003185/change-position-of-jquery-tooltip-arrow)

but still not get any thing done.

```
$(function() {
$( document ).tooltip({

position: {
     my: "center bottom-20",
    at: "center top",
    using: function( position, feedback ) {
      $( this ).css( position );
      $( "<div>" )
        .addClass( "arrow" )
        .addClass( feedback.vertical )
        .addClass( feedback.horizontal )
        .appendTo( this );
    }
  }

});
});
```

Here is my fiddle [Jquery UI tooltip](http://jsfiddle.net/messi1987/rtdz9n96/)

Which shows the arrow above the link.

Comment: change this line my: "center bottom-20", to my: "right-30", and just let me knw whether this is the thing that u need!!

Comment: @SUDHIR nope it moved the tooltip to left of anchor tag and the arrow is still pointing towards bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Alternate Solution:**
You can Use jBox jQuery ToolTip which works good for you.
Here is the [Link](http://allinworld99.blogspot.com/2014/10/j-box-jquery-plugin-jquery-best-tooltip.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $( document ).tooltip({

    position: {
         my: "left+40",
        at: "center right",
        using: function( position, feedback ) {
          $( this ).css( position );
          $( "<div>" )
            .addClass( "arrow" )
            .addClass( feedback.vertical )
            .addClass( feedback.horizontal )
            .appendTo( this );
        }
      }

    });
```

You got to adjust the arrow
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rtdz9n96/15/)

Comment: moved to the right thats good but the arrow is still pointing downward, how to adjust that pointing arrow accordingly i.e on the left of tool tip.